# Proving an inequality with logarithms

Tags: calculus, inequality

I made a proof of the following statement (call it, S1):

> $\textbf{S1:} $ If $x>0,$ then $$\dfrac{x-\ln (x+1)}{x \ln (x+1)} \leq \frac{1}{2}. $$

First of all, let's prove the following property (call it P1):

> $\textbf{P1}:$ If $x>0,$ then $$\ln (x) \geq 1- \frac{1}{x}. $$

$\textbf{Proof of P1:}$ Let $g(x)=\ln(x)+\frac{1}{x} -1,$ for $ x>0.$

Then  $g'(x)= \frac{x-1}{x^2}$ and $g'$ vanishes if and only if $x=1. $

We compute $g''$ and obtain 
$g''(x)=\frac{2-x}{x^3},$ and observe that $g''(1) = 1 >0. $

Since $g'(1)=0$ and $g''(1)>0,$ the Second Derivative Criterion tells us that $g$ has a minimum value at $x=1,$ and at $x=1, $ $g(x)=0$.

Then I claim $^{(*)}$ that $g(x)=0$ is the minimum value of $g$ at $(0, \infty)$, that is, $g(x) \geq 0$ $\forall x >0$.

So $\textbf{P1}$ is true.

$\textbf{Proof of S1:}$ Let $f(x)= (x+2) \ln (x+1) - 2x,$ for $x>0.$

Then for all $x>0:$
$\begin{eqnarray*}
f'(x)&=& \ln (x+1) + \frac{x+2}{x+1} -2\\
&=& \ln (x+1) + \frac{1}{x+1} -1 \\
&=& g(x+1)\geq 0,
\end{eqnarray*}$

where $g$ is defined as in proof of $\textbf{P1}.$

Then $f$ is (not necessarily strictly) increasing over $(0, \infty)$, and since $f(0)=0$, then $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in (0,\infty).$

Then $\textbf{S1}$ is true.

Well, now I have two questions (that I would be grateful if you answer):

1. Is the proof of the $\textbf{P1}$ correct? Specially in the part $(*)$ when I claim that $ g(x)=0$ is the minimum value of $g$ at $(0, \infty)$, that is, $g(x) \geq 0$ $\forall x >0.$
2. Is the proof of $\textbf{S1}$ correct?

Thanks in advance, I'm just improving skills at my problem solving.

Answer (score 3):

Your proofs of P1 and S1 are mostly correct. However, you could strengthen your claim that $(1,0)$ is a global minimum for $g$ by recognizing that $g'(x) < 0$ for $x<1$ and $g'(x) > 0$ for $x>1$, which means that $g(x)$ is always decreasing for $0<x<1$ and is always increasing for $x>1$. Hence $x=1$ yields a global minimum for $g$.

Comment: The second derivative criterion only guarantees that (1,0) is a local minimum of g? It is intuitively true in the sense that derivative is a local property... or I'm missing something?

Comment: Yes it only guarantees that it's a local minimum. Is it true that the second derivative is always greater than zero for $x>0$? If so then it's a global minimum.

Comment: For instance, consider the function $f(x) = (x-2)^2(x+2)^2(x+3)(x-3)$. It has $3$ local minimums and the second derivative is positive at each minimum. However, its global minimum occurs at $x=0$.